# NetworkxError raise an ImportError

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation, networkx

I can't import NetworkX on Windows 8, Python 2.7.8. I used pip to install the NetworkX package, the result was successful.

Trying to import NetworkX in the python shell got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxH3V.png).

The error raise here:

```
from Networkx import NetworkxError
result: ImportError: cannot import name NetworkxError
```

How I can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import `Networkx`, just do:

```
import networkx
```

and if you want `NetworkxError`, then:

```
from networkx.exception import NetworkXError
```

Comment: if you importing networkx it seems you do import the hole package.

Comment: if you only want `NetworkXError` then include only second line in your code.

Comment: the error 'cannot import name NetworkxError' raises by 'import networkx'

Comment: @DimitryDemin can you tell me which class you want to import?

Comment: the hole networkx package. by `import networkx` I got this error: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zxH3V.png)

Comment: you are not importing `networkx`, you are trying to import `NetworkXError`. Since you want the whole package, just do `import networkx`